# LoadError: Unable to autoload constant, RSpec can't find the class in my services folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

**Edit: Issue due to careless typo.**

I am trying to run my test so that a user can call on the JWT token generator and receive a token. However RSpec can't seem to find the JWTService class defined in my services directory. Do I need to do something with the Rails autoloader? I already have services defined in spring.rb. Thanks for your help!

[image]

spec/requests/contracts_api_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper' 
require 'jwt_service'
RSpec.describe "ContractsApi", type: :request do
  def authenticated_header(user)
      contents = { :user_id => user.id, :expiration => 24.hours.from_now.to_i }
      token = JWTService.encode(contents)
      { 'Authorization': "Bearer #{token}" }
  end

  describe "POST #create" do
    let (:contract_params) do
      {
        vendor: "Lebara",
        starts_on: "2018-12-12",
        ends_on: "2018-12-16",
        price: "15",
      }
    end
    before(:each) do
      @user = User.create(full_name: "Jason Bourne", email: "jbourne@test.com", password: "123456")
    end

    it 'creates a new contract' do
      post api_v1_user_contracts_path(@user), { params: contract_params, headers: authenticated_header(@user) }
      expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
    end
  end
end
```

app/services/jwt_service.rb

```
class JwtService
  def self.encode(payload)
    JWT.encode(payload, Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base, 'HS256')
  end

  def self.decode(token)
    body, = JWT.decode(token, Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base,
                       true, algorithm: 'HS256')
    HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(body)
  rescue JWT::ExpiredSignature
    nil
  end
end
```

spring.rb

```
%w(
  .ruby-version
  .rbenv-vars
  tmp/restart.txt
  tmp/caching-dev.txt
  app/services
).each { |path| Spring.watch(path) }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You spelled it wrong. You defined your class `JwtService` in jwt_service.rb, not `JWTService`

Comment: Thank you so much, I was reading up on autoloading magic and rails require intricacies when I should've look there first. Issue resolved

Comment: No problem. The detail is in the error message. That tells you Rails found the right file. So it's not an autoload issue.